# Rails 4 app not loading CSS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app hosted on Digital Ocean (nginx server) managed by cloud66.
The app is minimizing all files under the assets folder, but seems not be loading them? or at least not applying my custom.css file and not loading the background image.
I have been trying everything possible, read many articles about the asset pipelines and still site is showing with no BG image and my rtl setting (right to left property in my custom.css) are not getting applied.
It is working well on my local dev environement, but when I run it on my local machine as production environment, I am having the same issue.

production.rb file

```
Tafqit::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  config.eager_load = true
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true



  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_files = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx


  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # using the action page cashing gem, https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching
  config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/deploy"


end
```

The live site is on [t a f q i t .com] note the background image is not loading and the custom css to move the address line to the right is not working.
I have done all the commands related to manually cleaning the cache clobbing the assets and precmopiling..etc
gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 5.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  gem 'geo_ip', '~> 0.5.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails-rtl', '~> 2.3.1.0'
  gem 'zeroclipboard-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 2.2.1'
  gem 'tzinfo-data'
  gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "actionpack-page_caching", "~> 1.0.2"
gem "actionpack-action_caching", "~> 1.1.1"

# Use unicorn as the app server
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end
```

when checking the page source

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/main_pages.css?body=1" />
```

clicking on custom.css and main-pages.css link from the source page give same result:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check that your application running in production environment.

Comment: Thanks @maxd, it seems that cloud66 is making my app runs on dev mode instead of production..because I am on their free plan.
Thanks for pointing that out, so on dev mode it won't load my css? or what exactly is happening? What should I do?

Comment: Try to enable production mode or serve assets through Rails application (config.serve_static_files) (this is bad for performance).

Comment: what should I do to server assets through rails app? should I add config.serve_static_files = true to development.erb?